# Deployer Laravel failing on migration

Tags: laravel, php-deployer

So I'm using deployer to deploy my Laravel application, and everything seems to work right up until migrations. It keeps attempting to use the default variables `forge@localhost` even though I've tried both copying a .env file into the folder and setting the environment variables globally. (I'm not sure which one of those is considered best practice so I would appreciate if someone could let me know).

But either way it still errors out because it's using the default for some reason.

[image]

Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: please, provide the errors .

Comment: @c4f4t0r added them.

Comment: use this command `composer dump-autoload`. And it solves your problem

Comment: @A.ANoman Where would I put that in my deployer config? I tried adding it before migrate and it still doesn't work.

Comment: added .env file to shared_files?

Comment: @pudov.maxim I don't know how to do that. There is 0 documentation on it and everytime I try add say `/srv/.env` to the shared files it directly adds `/srv/.env` rather than just the `.env` file.

Comment: @Borassign I about this line: `add('shared_files', [ '.env' ]); `
And can you show whole config?